# Given an Int Array, Find Two Integers with the Smallest Difference that has the Sum M

Tags: python, list, sorting, search, integer

Given an unordered integer list, print two integers that total to `m` in this manner `int1 int2` (int 1 is less than or equal to int 2, and they are separated by a space). Assume that there is always a solution for `m` in the integer list. **int1 and int2 must be positive integers**.

If there are multiple solutions, print the integer pair with the **least difference**.

Example:

```
Li = [2, 6, 8, 10, 4]
m = 10

Output: 
4 6
```

Here's my code but according to our compiler (this is an exercise in our class), I have wrong outputs for the hidden test cases.

```
li = [2, 6, 8, 10, 4]
m = int(input())
selection = {}                  # I created a dictionary to put all pairs, sort them
                                # and print the pair with the least difference.

for j in li:

index = li.index(j)             
temp = li.pop(index)

    if m-j in li and j != m:          # checks if m-j is present in the list, and j
                                      # does not equal to m, since we're only looking
                                      # for positive integer pairs

        if abs(j - (m-j)) not in selection :            # don't have to rewrite in the dict
                                                             # if pair is already written.

            selection[abs(j - (m-j))] = [min(j, m-j), max(j, m-j)]

    li.insert(index, temp)

output = min(selection.keys()) # gets the pair  with the minimum difference in the dict

print(*selection[output])
```

**UPDATE: Code works!**

Comment: What is budget?  It seems to suddenly appear in the code?    I think everywhere you have budget, you mean `m`.   There are other ways to improve your code, but you weren't asking about that.

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. already updated. I figured using `budget` makes the code look longer, so I changed it to `m`.

Comment: Update: I think I found the loophole to my solution. In the case of the same pair (ex. `5 5`), it fails to check if there are two `5`s in the integer. My code is already updated.

Comment: So is the code still broken?  I should note that your last two lines can just be `min_key = min(selection.keys())`, and then your answer is `selection[min_key]`

Comment: Code works in the compiler after my fix, but thank you for that idea. I guess that's a faster way to get the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
Li = [2, 6, 8, 10, 4]
m = 10

#Output: 
#4 6

m_satisfied = []
for i in range(len(Li) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(Li)):
        if (Li[i] + Li[j]) == m:
            m_satisfied.append(tuple([Li[i], Li[j]]))

diff_dict = {i: abs(t[0] - t[1]) for i,t in enumerate(m_satisfied)}
least_diff = min(diff_dict.values())
ind_m_satisfied = [k for k, v in diff_dict.items() if v == least_diff]
res_int = [m_satisfied[i] for i in ind_m_satisfied]
print(res_int)
print(res_int[0][0], res_int[0][1])
```

Output:

```
[(6, 4)]
6 4
```

Comment: This runs at O(n^2), I think it's slower than my original code.

Comment: The loops I have can easily be replaced by list comprehension. Another reason to code so is what if you have more than one solution.